# Distance between 2 or more drop pins

Tags: iphone

I was doing a small assignment,in which i was finding the distance between Green drop pin and red drop pins.The green pin shows the user location and red pins shows his friend's location.But i don't have any idea how can do it?So please if somebody help me regarding my problem,I shall be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `distanceFromLocation:`.

Pls go through the [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)

**Update:**

```
// Assumption: lat1, lon1 and lat2, lon2 are double values containing the coordinates

CLLocation *firstLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1] autorelease];
CLLocation *secondLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:lon2] autorelease];
CLLocationDistance distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation];
```

Comment: can u explain more please because i have so manny red pins i mean co-ordinates .It'll be gr8 help if u give me example regarding the problem please..